# Call QtWidget parent method from child

Tags: c++, qt, getter

I'm trying to get some attributes of a parent widget: `SamplerModule` from its children: `InstrumentSelector`.

From the `InstrumentSelector` constructor, I run `parent->metaObject()->className()` which gives me the right name (SamplerModule). So I'm sure that I'm in the right place to call one of my public method, for example `getT()` defined as a public method in my `SamplerModule` header and cpp file.

But, when I call this function, I'm getting this error:

> \app\widgets\instrumentselector.cpp:23: erreur : 'class QWidget' has no member named 'getT'
>        msgBox.setText(parent->getT());

So I think that's C++ and Qt basics but I'm still learning that.

Does someone have an idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the code, it's hard to say for sure, but my guess is that you've defined "parent" as a "QWidget *", so the compiler has no idea that it's actually a base pointer to a SamplerModule. You need to either cast "parent" to a SamplerModule pointer, or declare it that way to start with. And yes, this is pure C++; it's not related to Qt.

Comment: Thanks! So as my code is pretty long I'll try to make it short. The Selector signature is `InstrumentSelector::InstrumentSelector(QWidget *parent) : QPushButton(parent)`. I've 36 of these buttons in my `SamplerModule`UI file. And I'm trying to run `parent->getT()ìn my buttons constructor. So yes, I feel that I have to give more informations to the `InstrumentSelector` Instances but I don't really understand how to do it. :/

Comment: So what you need is:  "SamplerModule *module = dynamic_cast <SamplerModule *> (parent);" and then use "module->getT()". The dynamic cast will fail and return a null pointer if parent isn't actually a SamplerModule. You'll also want to read up on base and derived classes and how to use pointers for each. This is an important concept and without a good understanding of it, you'll be very frustrated. :)

Comment: Thank you very much! But in that case, the `module` will be a "new instance" of `SamplerModule` right ? Not the one where the `InstrumentSelector` are created right ? So if I need to get value wich is set in this specific Instance of `SamplerModule` if can't get it this way ?

Comment: No, "module" isn't a new instance; the dynamic_cast tells the compiler to safely determine if the parent is actually a SamplerModule and then gives you a pointer to that same SamplerModule. After the cast, both "parent" and "module" point to the same object.

Comment: Thanks, so as my buttons are created in the SamplerModule QtDesigner ui it should work? The variable with getT is getting is set in my SamplerModule constructor, so it should work, no? ATM it does not work, I've segmentation fault, so it means that the value I'm getting has no instance. I don't understand why! Thanks again mate!

Comment: If "parent" has a valid value, and parent is derived from SamplerModule, then the dynamic_cast will return a non-zero value. If the dynamic_cast is returning 0, then your parent class isn't actually a SamplerModule instance; it's something else.